# Sort matches by closer to the beginning of the string

Tags: sphinx

There is a table, which contains site URLs.
I want to sort Sphinx results in a way: "the closer keyword to the beginning of string - the more relevant"

"foobar.com, barfoo.com, barbarfoo.com" is correct result set for keyword "foo"

I have tried :

```
$s = new SphinxClient;
$s->setServer("localhost", 9312);
$s->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_ALL);
$s->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_RELEVANCE);
$s->SetFieldWeights(array(
                         'id' => 0,
                         'url' => 1000,
                    ));
$result = $s->query("foo");
```

Unfortunately I get result, that sorted by id.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, dont think sphinx can do that directly. There are various ranking factors but all based on words.

Can match part words using the 'min_prefix_len', but cant get 'where in the word' the match happens, to be able to rank by it.

The only way may be able to get to work with sphinx, would be to use wordbreaker
http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2013/01/29/a-new-tool-in-the-trunk-wordbreaker/

to index your domains names as seperate words. Hoping that your domains would be split correctly at "foo bar com", "bar foo com", "bar bar foo com" - which then could rank by word position, eg `min_hit_pos`
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#field-factors